# How to replace a single slash '/' in a string excluding the slash characters in the '://' pattern

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am trying to find a way to replace single slash character '/' from a string except the slashes in 'https://' or not in 'http://'

```
a="https://example.com/example/page/"
```

I would like to substitute '/' for example with '%' but not the slash characters in 'https://' or not in 'http://' so that at the end I have the result like:

```
a="https://example.com%example%page%"
```

I tried

```
re.sub('(?<!:\/)\/', '%', a)
```

in python but it is not correct.

Comment: http is an example device. So is `//` file root. So, there are many standard devices/protocols, etc. You're best bet is to leave all of them be and match a single /. You can do it with `(?<!/)/(?!/)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(https?|ftps?)://|/', lambda x: x.group(0) if x.group(1) else '%', s)
```

**Details**

- `(https?|ftps?)://` - matches and captures into Group 1 `http`/`https`/`ftp`/`ftps` (add more if needed) and then matches `://`
- `|` - or
- `/` - matches `/` in any other context

If Group 1 is matched, the whole match is pasted back, else, the `/` is replaced with `%`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/A8mHfP):

```
import re
s = 'https://example.com/example/page/'
print(re.sub(r'(https?|ftps?)://|/', lambda x: x.group(0) if x.group(1) else '%', s))
# => https://example.com%example%page%
```